# File input Error

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to input a file in My code which contain a list of integers with New line 
I used the following code to input to content in a file

```
int main()
{
FILE* f = fopen("Integers.txt", "r");
int n = 0, i = 0;
int numbers[5]; // assuming there are only 5 numbers in array input

while( fscanf(f, "%d\n", &n) > 0 ) // parse %d followed by '\n'
{
    numbers[i++] = n;
}

fclose(f);
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault so please help.

Comment: Integers.txt is contained five or more?

Comment: it has 10000 integers

Comment: This is the link  http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/algo1/programming_prob/IntegerArray.txt

Comment: `numbers[i++] = n;` --> `numbers[i++] = n;if(i==5)break;`

Comment: In Final iteration you have to check for `EOF` , if file have exact 5 numbers.otherwise do iteration based on control variable inside loop.

Comment: Change to `while(i < 5 && fscanf(f, "%d\n", &n) > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try this, since the array `numbers` is only `5`.

```
int main()
{    
int n = 0, i = 0;
int numbers[5]; // assuming there are only 5 numbers in array input

FILE* f = fopen("Integers.txt", "r");

if (f != NULL)
{    
    for (i=0; i<(sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int)); i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(f, "%d\n", &n) > 0)
            numbers[i] = n;
        else
            break;
    }
    fclose(f);
}
}
```

The array `numbers[5]` is in stack and accessing it out of bounds will corrupt the stack.

Comment: `sizeof(numbers)` --> `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(*numbers)`

Comment: I am still getting the segmentation falut

Comment: @user3692108: Check whether `fopen()` returns NULL or not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

```
main()
{
 FILE* f = fopen("Integers.txt", "r");
 int n,i;
 int numbers[5]; // assuming there are only 5 numbers in array input

 for (i=0; i<5; i++)
 {
 fscanf(f, "%d", &n)
 numbers[i] = n;
 }

fclose(f);
}
```